# Sitecore - Importing new languagues

Tags: translation, sitecore

Our sitecore site is currrently only in English, at the moment the xml for the site is being translated into spanish, french & german. right now I am trying to get an idea of whats involved in the language import procedure and the pitfalls etc that may be encountered when the translated code is added into the cms, can anyone explain any best practices for language import or any good websites that explain this procedure?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "translating the XML"? Do you mean your site content? And what do you mean by "translated code" being added to the CMS? Are you translating content in the Sitecore client?

Comment: Apologies James, We have exported the sitecore content into xml format which has been sent off to our translation company so they can make the translations and then we can hopefully reimport the xml.

Comment: OK thanks, makes sense now, sorry I have no idea how to help!

Answer (score 1):

There are companies that sell software to handle translations using Sitecore content so there are multiple solutions here.  [Clay Tablet Technologies](http://www.clay-tablet.com/home.asp) would be one example that is used where I work but there could be others out there to consider though another part is how complex is the structure of your content.